# Angular Material Table with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a table with elements taken from api call.

In my **component.ts**:

```
   public tableData: any = []
   public displayColumns: any = []
   public dataSource: any

   ngOnInit(){
     this.getApi()
   } 
    
    getApi(){
      this.apicall.api1(this.store_id).subscribe((stores) => {
      this.tableData.push(stores);
      stores.forEach((singleStore) => {
        this.displayColumns.push(singleStore.store_id))
    })
    })
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
    }
```

Now I want to obtain a table like this:

| 1023 | 1024 | 1025 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100€ | 200€ | 300€ |

Like the header (first row) is the store_id, the second row is the budget.

**component.html**

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
            {{ displayColumns | json }}
            <ng-container *ngFor="let storeCol of displayColumns; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{storeCol}}">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{storeCol.store_id}}</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[storeCol.budget_mean]}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

But I receive errors like:

ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "1023".

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe the reason is that `displayColumns` pointer stays the same. Try `this.displayColumns = [...this.displayColumns];` after `stores.forEach`

Comment: @Benny thank you for answer, but I receive the same error